# Fragment vs Activity Battery Drain

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, android-activity, android-memory

I have been developing each of my "page" in my app using `Activity`.

I am wondering *if this will consume more memory* or will this affect *performance badly compared to `Fragments`*?

Can anyone provide an explanation please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am wondering if this will consume more memory or will this affect performance badly compared to Fragments?

Whether you use fragments or not has nothing to do with performance, memory or battery use. You can create the same UI with Activities as with Fragments. The whole point of using fragments is that it makes parts of you UI reusable.